# VBA Range Selection

Tags: vba, excel

I use this script to clear the contents of an adjacent cell if a certain text is found. However, I don't know how to change the range from the current region to strictly columns A to T. I tried `ActiveSheet.Range("A:T").Select` but that did not work.

Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code:

```
Sub Clear_Text()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    For Each rng2 In rng1
        If rng2 Like "Error" Or _
        rng2 Like "Mistake" Then rng2.Offset(, 1).ClearContents
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a "Type Mismatch" error still. I thought it was because it was going outside of the range but maybe there is another problem with the code?

Comment: Try: `Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Columns("A:T").Cells`.

Answer (score 3):

looping through all cells of a given range could be time consuming

you could use `Find()` function to jump to relevant cells only:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Clear_Text()
    With Range("T1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        CheckAndClear .Cells, "Error"
        CheckAndClear .Cells, "Mistake"
    End With
End Sub

Sub CheckAndClear(rng As Range, strng As String)
    Dim f As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    With rng
        Set f = .Find(what:=strng, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart) '<--|with 'lookat:=xlPart' parameter specification makes you catch cell that contains the searched string
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = f.Address
            Do
                f.Offset(, 1).ClearContents
                Set f = .FindNext(f)
            Loop While f.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow that is quicker!

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this to limit search range to columns `A:T`:

```
Sub Clear_Text()
    Dim cl As Range

    For Each cl In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:T" & Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count)
        If cl Like "Error" Or cl Like "Mistake" Then
            cl.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```